# Embedding Python inside python application for scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've written an application in python 3. I plan on releasing it as a pyInstaller binary all in one file so that anybody can run the app on their system. I'd like to add a way so that user can script inside the application as well. So I'd like to expose python interpreter + some classes of the app for controls.

How can I do this?

The app runs PySide2 as gui + quite few more libs. Not sure if this matters tho. I will provide a text edit ide style for coding.

TIA

To dear mod that decided to Close the question. I don't know how to ask precisely for what I want to do. Its a general question to get general feedback so that I can understand my problem & to ask more questions in future with more focus.

Comment: The Python interpreter is embedded in your pyinstaller exe. Note that only the modules included in your exe will be available - I guess you should be able to add more to the pyinstaller spec file.. There might be security concerns as presumably the user’s script will be able to access logins/passwords.

Comment: Thank you @barny ! That sounds interesting. I'll read more on spec file... I know I did a lot of work to make it run my app in 1st place. I wonder if it will natively include all content of python venv that I use to build stuff in or just the minimum it need.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to run code specified at runtime using [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). This will also allow you to access any functions or classes you've defined. Note that you should never allow any of the input to this function to be taken from unsanitized data from untrusted network connections.

Comment: Hmmm I see. So this means if I take the output of text/IDE that user input in script editor, I can then run it via exec("print('hello')") and get a proper output? This sounds brilliant. I take then I can pre-import some modules to the code so user gets access to some internal modules. When you say ```unsanitized data from untrusted network connections.``` Do you mean that socket/network connection should not allow to call upon that exec() call?

Comment: Yes you should be able to pre-import some modules, and what I mean by that statement is that you shouldn't request data and then insert it into the code because this can lead to remote code execution vulnerabilities.